# Run registry key Windows 7 x64

Tags: boot, windows-registry

I'm trying to run a script on start-up using:

```
 HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run    Reg_SZ:"C:\Temp\File.bat"
```

It works fine on X32, but not on x64. Is there maybe a policy locking this from running? UAC is off.

Comment: We need additional information.  How can you tell the script is never being ran?

Comment: For test purposes I used a simple display which just echoed some text and paused, also I do not see a cmd.exe in the processes task window.

Comment: I am going to guess you using the wrong registry key.

Comment: I thought I must have been mistyping it, but I've triple check the directory spelling, and location. I've tried using the run key under HKCU and HKLM, like I mentioned it works fine under x32 in HKCU.

Answer (score -1):

On windows 64-bit you must always put 64 bit entries in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node ore one of the "Wow6432Node" folders accordingly

Hope this helps